# keyboard.is_pressed() Not working properly

Tags: python, keyboard

I have some simple code to print "Hello" when I press my "ctrl" (control) key.
Here is the code:

```
while(True):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        print("Hello")
```

This works but when I press my control key it prints 16 times instead of once. I tried using 'keyboard.read_key() == 'ctrl' but I got the same issue.

Comment: talk about false advertisement, pypi homepage said no dependencies and pip installed 117 pyobjc package :D

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response. You can add a break statement at the end of your if statement like this:

```py
while(True):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        print("Hello")
        break
```

If you want a debounce it:

```py
deb = False
while(True):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl') and not deb:
        deb = True
        print("Hello")
        wait(5) # debounce duration
        debounce = False
```

Hopes this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `while` is having no delay and the process keep entering in to the `while` loop. Although, the key press is just one from the user's perspective yet the computer is actually seeing multiple presses of those due to the `while` loop.

I am not sure how to effectively verify this but if we press the key just once and add a delay as below, we'll be able observe the difference:

```
import keyboard
import time
while(True):
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just tried that I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Did you press the ctrl key or any other key? Please tell your platform and the python version as well. I have tried the above on windows 10 and python3.9.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.8.3. I am just pressing the ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the following logic:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
    keyboard.release('ctrl')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    """Do something"""
```

Depending on the application, you may need to make sure that the key is released before continuing, **keyboard.release()** comes in handy. I also agree with @KrishnaChaurasia that a delay must be added to make sure that the computer does not perform many cycles in what humans perceive as an instant.